# validation but when I use <select>

Tags: jquery

The code works successfully for validation but when I use select it doesn't work

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  // click on next button
  jQuery('.form-wizard-next-btn').click(function() {
    var parentFieldset = jQuery(this).parents('.wizard-fieldset');
    var currentActiveStep = jQuery(this).parents('.form-wizard').find('.form-wizard-steps .active');
    var next = jQuery(this);
    var nextWizardStep = true;
    parentFieldset.find('.wizard-required').each(function() {
      var thisValue = jQuery(this).val();

      if (thisValue == "") {
        jQuery(this).siblings(".wizard-form-error").slideDown();
        nextWizardStep = false;
      } else {
        jQuery(this).siblings(".wizard-form-error").slideUp();
      }
    });
    if (nextWizardStep) {
      next.parents('.wizard-fieldset').removeClass("show", "400");
      currentActiveStep.removeClass('active').addClass('activated').next().addClass('active', "400");
      next.parents('.wizard-fieldset').next('.wizard-fieldset').addClass("show", "400");
      jQuery(document).find('.wizard-fieldset').each(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).hasClass('show')) {
          var formAtrr = jQuery(this).attr('data-tab-content');
          jQuery(document).find('.form-wizard-steps .form-wizard-step-item').each(function() {
            if (jQuery(this).attr('data-attr') == formAtrr) {
              jQuery(this).addClass('active');
              var innerWidth = jQuery(this).innerWidth();
              var position = jQuery(this).position();
              jQuery(document).find('.form-wizard-step-move').css({
                "left": position.left,
                "width": innerWidth
              });
            } else {
              jQuery(this).removeClass('active');
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
  //click on previous button
  jQuery('.form-wizard-previous-btn').click(function() {
    var counter = parseInt(jQuery(".wizard-counter").text());;
    var prev = jQuery(this);
    var currentActiveStep = jQuery(this).parents('.form-wizard').find('.form-wizard-steps .active');
    prev.parents('.wizard-fieldset').removeClass("show", "400");
    prev.parents('.wizard-fieldset').prev('.wizard-fieldset').addClass("show", "400");
    currentActiveStep.removeClass('active').prev().removeClass('activated').addClass('active', "400");
    jQuery(document).find('.wizard-fieldset').each(function() {
      if (jQuery(this).hasClass('show')) {
        var formAtrr = jQuery(this).attr('data-tab-content');
        jQuery(document).find('.form-wizard-steps .form-wizard-step-item').each(function() {
          if (jQuery(this).attr('data-attr') == formAtrr) {
            jQuery(this).addClass('active');
            var innerWidth = jQuery(this).innerWidth();
            var position = jQuery(this).position();
            jQuery(document).find('.form-wizard-step-move').css({
              "left": position.left,
              "width": innerWidth
            });
          } else {
            jQuery(this).removeClass('active');
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
  //click on form submit button
  jQuery(document).on("click", ".form-wizard .form-wizard-submit", function() {
    var parentFieldset = jQuery(this).parents('.wizard-fieldset');
    var currentActiveStep = jQuery(this).parents('.form-wizard').find('.form-wizard-steps .active');
    parentFieldset.find('.wizard-required').each(function() {
      var thisValue = jQuery(this).val();
      if (thisValue == "") {
        jQuery(this).siblings(".wizard-form-error").slideDown();
      } else {
        jQuery(this).siblings(".wizard-form-error").slideUp();
      }
    });
  });
  // focus on input field check empty or not
  jQuery(".form-control").on('focus', function() {
    var tmpThis = jQuery(this).val();
    if (tmpThis == '') {
      jQuery(this).parent().addClass("focus-input");
    } else if (tmpThis != '') {
      jQuery(this).parent().addClass("focus-input");
    }
  }).on('blur', function() {
    var tmpThis = jQuery(this).val();
    if (tmpThis == '') {
      jQuery(this).parent().removeClass("focus-input");
      jQuery(this).siblings('.wizard-form-error').slideDown("3000");
    } else if (tmpThis != '') {
      jQuery(this).parent().addClass("focus-input");
      jQuery(this).siblings('.wizard-form-error').slideUp("3000");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="nice-select" name="IDS">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<div class="wizard-form-error"></div>
```

Comment: There's no code that checks `.nice-select`. None of the JS code you posted seems relevant for this HTML.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, please do take the time to read the [tour] and [ask] pages.   In your case, please also read [mcve], with the emphasis on *mininal* - as noted above, there's far too much js and surely most of it is not relevant.

Comment: <select class="form-wizard" name="IDS">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<div class="wizard-form-error"></div>
class responsible for verification is 'form-wizard'